# Constantly get invalid scope error after udating my identityserver4

Tags: asp.net, validation, identityserver4

I had *identityProviderService* working with my API and web app, then I updated i updated my dependecies(identityServer4) and that resulted constantly in the following error either I use code or I hybrid.

> **IdentityServer4 Error: Invalid_scope**

I checked the log and the scope was fine but I can resolve why I keep getting this error! The details as follows:

My local Idp (Identityserver4) log and the main error =>

> ```sh
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information:
> Invoking IdentityServer endpoint:
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
> IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultResourceValidator: Error: Scope
> Bd.Web.Api not found in store.
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Error: Request validation
> failed IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Information: {  
> "ClientId": "BdWebAppClientId",   "ClientName": "Bd web Client
> Application",   "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:xxxxx/signin-oidc", 
> "AllowedRedirectUris": [
>     "https://localhost:44386/signin-oidc"   ],   "SubjectId": "anonymous",   "ResponseType": "code",   "ResponseMode": "form_post", 
> "GrantType": "authorization_code",   "RequestedScopes": "openid
> profile Bd.Web.Api",   "State":
> "CfDJ8Foioa24zShFmzIFmkTbGBTrbiiEwQYmHGMRUN7FwsfKMgY2-olWJA1XVlAkA0uCWIR6HhMdu2X1exzVKTNFTcAD456Z0r3es5ki377uBEJgjA9jmyQFWWzTZV6_7GEmIC39xUh_b_YAqXgtzO0olZ52beNFuxruk_NshL47NhwcaETCH2cy3XTvRN0NTxZHmxVWglo13iSE7RVpNghHc7pBW7jCv7cB2RldQnEvsJ4s56AdiICw9sdKEJ5mQNoXngshanycX4MmD3qaW0TX6knY43pAqMuPgEEVqd7BXKt_koQfiQuAP3pQNbsyOAb1jtoZ8egUHiKgXjofs8ci2i4",
> "PromptMode": "",   "Raw": {
>     "client_id": "BdWebAppClientId",
>     "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:xxxxx/signin-oidc",
>     "response_type": "code",
>     "scope": "openid profile Bd.Web.Api",
>     "response_mode": "form_post",
>     "nonce": "637284460180108591.ZjIxYjhlZGEtYjk0Mi00M2UxLWExNWItOGYzMjhjODEyMGQzZmU5NjZmZDAtOTQwYi00YTFlLWJlMWUtM2U3YzBhM2NmNjQ4",
>     "state": "CfDJ8Foioa24zShFmzIFmkTbGBTrbiiEwQYmHGMRUN7FwsfKMgY2-olWJA1XVlAkA0uCWIR6HhMdu2X1exzVKTNFTcAD456Z0r3es5ki377uBEJgjA9jmyQFWWzTZV6_7GEmIC39xUh_b_YAqXgtzO0olZ52beNFuxruk_NshL47NhwcaETCH2cy3XTvRN0NTxZHmxVWglo13iSE7RVpNghHc7pBW7jCv7cB2RldQnEvsJ4s56AdiICw9sdKEJ5mQNoXngshanycX4MmD3qaW0TX6knY43pAqMuPgEEVqd7BXKt_koQfiQuAP3pQNbsyOAb1jtoZ8egUHiKgXjofs8ci2i4",
>     "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
>     "x-client-ver": "5.5.0.0"   }
> ```

My config comprises of three classes User, Resources and Client as follows:

```cs
public class Users
{
    public static List<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<TestUser> {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                Username = "scott",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "scott@scottbrady91.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
                }
            }
        };
    }
}


public class Resources
{
    public static  IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Address()
        };
    }


    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("Bd.Web.Api", "Bd Web Api") {
                Description = "BD API Access",
                //UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"},
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("secret".Sha256())}
            }
        };
    }

}


public class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client> {
            new Client {
                ClientId = "BdWebAppClientId",
                ClientName = "Bd web Client Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = false,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                AllowedScopes = 
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                    "Bd.Web.Api"
                },
                RedirectUris =  new List<string>{"https://localhost:44386/signin-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>{ "https://localhost:44386/sigout-callback-oidc" }
            
            }

        };
    }
}


public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.Ids())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.Apis())
            .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            //endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        });
    }
}
```

My web app startup as follows:

```cs
 public class Startup
 {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {

                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            

            services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            };

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddTransient<BearerTokenHandler>();

            services.AddHttpClient("ApiClient", client =>
            {
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://bandapi.azurewebsites.net/api/");
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44301/api/");
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://192.168.1.25:44301/api/");
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
                
               

            }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();

            services.AddHttpClient("IdpClient", client =>
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:xxxxx/");
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
            }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "BdWebAppCookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";


                //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
         .AddCookie("BdWebAppCookies"  /*CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme*/, options =>
         {
             options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authentication/AccessDenied";
         })
         .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc" /*OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme*/, options =>
         {

             options.Authority = "https://localhost:xxxx/";
             //options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
             options.ClientId = "BdWebAppClientId";

             
             options.Scope.Add("openid");
             options.Scope.Add("profile");
             options.Scope.Add("address");

             options.Scope.Add("Bd.Web.Api");

             
             options.ClientSecret = "secret";
             options.ResponseType = "code";
             options.UsePkce = false;
             options.SignInScheme = "BdWebAppCookies";
            
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 20):

In IdentityServer4 4.x the handling of api scopes was changed. Now you need to define all available api scopes and provide them to the configuration.

The updated documentation shows how it's done. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#scopes

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
{
    return new List<ApiScope>
    {
        new ApiScope(name: "read",   displayName: "Read your data."),
        new ApiScope(name: "write",  displayName: "Write your data."),
        new ApiScope(name: "delete", displayName: "Delete your data.")
    };
}
```

Then add the scopes to your IdentityServer configuration:

```
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes());
```

Furthermore you need to add the scopes to your already defined ApiResources as described here: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#api-resources

```
public static readonly IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("invoices", "Invoice API")
        {
            Scopes = { "invoice.read", "invoice.pay", "manage" }
        },

        new ApiResource("customers", "Customer API")
        {
            Scopes = { "customer.read", "customer.contact", "manage" }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Found it in the documentation here after reading this: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=v4#migration-steps-to-v4

Comment: Note that you can also just add the ApiScopes only in place of the resources if you have a simple api. Just replace ApiResource with ApiScope and it will work as it did in 3.x.

Answer (score -1):

I was had the same problem after updating to .NET Core 3.1 and IndentityServer4 V4.0.0. Only way I could get it to work is to remove the scope parameter on the client API request, using Angular 9 with angular-oauth2-oidc V9.2.1

```
    const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .append('username', userName)
        .append('password', password)
        .append('client_id', this.clientId)
        .append('grant_type', 'password');

    this.oauthService.issuer = this.baseUrl;

    return from(this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument())
        .pipe(mergeMap(() => {
            return this.http.post(this.oauthService.tokenEndpoint, params, { headers: header });
        }));
```

**This is NOT the way to do this, if you remove the scope then none of the profile information will be returned.**

Comment: You probably need to add the new ApiScopes https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=v4#migration-steps-to-v4